# How do the Warlock spell slots and slot levels work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, spell-slots

The Warlock list confuses me. It says that you have spell slots but not the spell slot level and at level 20 you only get 4 spell slots? Is this right? Also it says slot level. I'm guessing that's for what level of spell you can pick at that level. Am I correct with that as well?

Comment: No reason to downvote. I literally went to look this up and came to this thread. I'm playing Baldur's Gate 3 and have no clue what a PHB is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes this is correct...

Under the sections:

### Spell Slots

PHB 107 (Emphasis mine)

> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have. The table also
>   shows what the level of those slots is; **all of your spell slots are
>   the same level.**

It further describes an example:

> For example, when you are 5th level, **you have two 3rd-level spell
>   slots.** To cast the 1st-level spell thunderwave, you must spend one of
>   those slots, and you cast it as a 3rd-level spell.

So assuming you reach 20th level you will have 15 spells known, with 4 usable slots every ***short rest*** and all spells you cast will be cast as 5th level.

### Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher

The slot levels indicate the highest level spells you know as well as the level at which you will cast the spell.

> A spell you choose must be of a level no higher than what’s shown in
>   the table's Slot Level column for your level. When you reach 6th
>   level, for example, you learn a new warlock spell, which can be 1st,
>   2nd, or 3rd level.

Mystic Arcanum are the higher "levels" of magic but they are treated somewhat differently as a balancing tool given how frequently a Warlock regains their slots.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. That answers my question very well.

Comment: To help clarify this answer, a _**short rest**_ is, "a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long, during which a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds."